# Sierra Chart DTC Java Socket Connection null terminator

Tags: java, sockets, byte, null-terminated

I am building an integration between Sierra Charts and my Java program, to accomplish this I am using their DTC protocol/framework which enables me to create a Socket Connection (from my Java program) and then pass messages back and forth.  However, I am currently stuck as they require me to pass a null terminator after each message, this is not something that is common from the Java world and has me stumped.  In order for their socket server to process my message it needs to contain the "null terminator" (https://www.sierrachart.com/index.php?page=doc/DTCProtocol.php#JSONEncoding)

I have reached out to Sierra Chart but they are not a Java shop and don't know have any insights.

I have included my sample Class, I am using Json encoding of the DTC message.  The basis of what I am doing is just opening a Java Socket and then passing a Json string which I have converted to a byte[] and and writing to the socket via BufferedOutputStream.  Then I am waiting for a response.  For convenience of my question I have brought my JSON into a String as a local variable.  My issue is that I can't crack the "null terminator" for my byte[] or String which I am converting.  I am wondering if anyone can shed some light on what a "null terminator" is; My assumption is that the Sierra Chart Socket Server is running C or C++ code and this is their delimiter, I just can't seem to grasp the Java equivalent.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Date;


public class SierraChartSocketClient {

public SierraChartSocketClient() {
String testServerName = "127.0.0.1";
int port = 11099;

try{
      Socket socket = openSocket(testServerName, port);
      socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);

      String result = loginToSocketAndRequestData(socket);

      System.out.println(result);

socket.close();
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

}

private String loginToSocketAndRequestData(Socket socket) throws Exception{
byte nullByte = 0x00;
String loginRequestString = "    {\"Type\":1,\"Integer_1\":1,\"HeartbeatIntervalInSeconds\":60\", \"ClientName\": \"Sample Application\"}";

String marketDataRequestCL = "{\"Type\":101,\"RequestAction\":\"SUBSCRIBE\",\"SymbolID\":1,\"Symbol\":\"CLF8\", \"Exchange\":\"NYMEX\"}";
String heartBeat = "{\"Type\":3,\"CurrentDateTime \":\"" + (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L) + "\" ";

try{
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
System.out.println("Sending Over Login Request: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
bufferedOutputStream.write(loginRequestString.getBytes());
bufferedOutputStream.write(nullByte);
bufferedOutputStream.flush();


StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String str = bufferedReader.readLine();
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println("Received Login Response: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());

bufferedOutputStream.write(heartBeat.getBytes());
bufferedOutputStream.flush();
System.out.println("Sending Heartbeat: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());

bufferedOutputStream.write(marketDataRequestCL.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
bufferedOutputStream.write(nullByte);

while((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
stringBuilder.append(str + "\n");
System.out.println(str);
}


return null;
}catch (IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
throw e;
}
}

private Socket openSocket(String server, int port) throws Exception{
Socket socket;

try{
InetAddress inteAddress = InetAddress.getByName(server);
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(inteAddress, port);

socket = new Socket();

int timeoutInMs = 45*1000; // 45 seconds
socket.connect(socketAddress, timeoutInMs);

return socket;

}catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
System.err.println("Timed out waiting for the socket.");
e.printStackTrace();
throw e;

}
}

public static void main(String[] args){
new SierraChartSocketClient();
}

}
```

Additionally I have tried this, (didn't work):

```
String loginRequestString = "{\"Type\":1,\"Integer_1\":1,\"HeartbeatIntervalInSeconds\":60\", \"ClientName\": \"Sample Application\"}";
byte[] loginRequestBytes = new byte[(loginRequestString.getBytes().length) + 1];
ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(loginRequestBytes);
bbuf.put(loginRequestString.getBytes());
```

And then I have tried this, (didn't work):

```
int len = loginRequestString.length();
byte b[] = new byte[len + 1];
ByteBuffer bbufj = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
enc.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(loginRequestString), bbufj, true);
```

I am sure this is something obvious that I am missing.  However, I haven't been able to make the logical jump so I am hoping someone out there can spot my mistake/error/missing logic.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to be trying this as well.

Null terminator isn't giving the problem, you already solved that.

The problem is that you're using BufferedReader. This won't work, you need to use BufferedInputStream.

Rgds